# use Timer to call the api request constantly in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, api, timer

I want to make an API request call until I get a specific value.

This may super basic stuff, but I'm a junior programmer, so still want some advice.

The function, `checkIsReady`, will return the boolean, and at the beginning, it returns false and after a while, it returns true.

```
struct IsReady: Codable {
    let isReady: Bool
}


func checkIsReady(id: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    
    var isReady: Bool = false
    
    AF.request("\(myendpoint)")
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            
            let decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            var result: IsReady?
            
            do {
                result = try decoder.decode(IsReady.self, from: data)
            } catch {
                print("error with get stream ready status: \(error)")
            }
            
            if result?.isReady {
                isReady = true
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(isReady)
            }
        }
}
```

So I know the function above returns false at first and takes some time to return true, I want to make a timer to call the function every 5 seconds until I get the truthy vlue.

Then I wrote the code below.

```
private var timer = Timer()
private let currentRetryCount = 0
private var isReady = false
private let myId = "AAA"

func apiCallTest() {
    if currentRetryCount > 9 && timer.isValid {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
        
    if !isReady && !timer.isValid {
            checkIsReady(id: myId) { [weak self] ready in
                if !ready {
                    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                        checkIsReady(id: myId) // what should I do for the completion?
                    })
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The problem is when I get ready as false in the completion in the apiCallTest function, I want to make a timer to call the checkIsReady every 5 sec (`timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true,...`), but not sure what to write in the completion block for the next call of checkIsReady function (the one I wrote `what should I do for the completion?`). I was wondering how other people solve this sort of calling the API every 5 sec stuff. BTW, if I write nil in the completion block, it gives me an error.

Comment: If I make no mistake,in the completion block you create a timer which loop permanently and recreate a supplementary one each 5 seconds. At the end you will have lot of timer running.In the completion handler of the AF.request you just need to slepp 5 seconds then call again AF.request. Do not forget to not relauch when isReady is True if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This would be how I would do it.

We make a initial call, if it fails it starts a timer calling the apiCallTest() the 2nd and following requests until it reaches the limit number of attempts.

This

```swift
var currentRetryCount = 0
var isReady = false
let myId = "AAA"
var timer: Timer? = nil

func apiCallTest() {
    checkIsReady(id: myId) {
        if $0 == true {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            self.isReady = true;
        } else {
            self.currentRetryCount = self.currentRetryCount + 1
            if currentRetryCount > 9 {
                self.timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then where you make the first call

```swift
checkIsReady(id: myId, completion: {
    if $0 == true {
        self.isReady = true // if the first attempt returns true no further action required
    } else {
        // if it fails we increment the count and start the timer
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true, block: { _ in apiCallTest() })
        self.currentRetryCount = self.currentRetryCount + 1
    }
})
```

The function `apiCallTest()` will answer all subsequent attempts